# How to Filter Inner Collection using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I need to filter the Inner Collection of a Collection using LINQ to fetch the records.

```
public class MobileModel : Notify
{
    private string _brand = string.Empty;
    private ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> _model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>();
    private string _os = string.Empty;

    public string Brand
    {
        get { return _brand; }
        set { _brand = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { _model = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string OS
    {
        get { return _os; }
        set { _os = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class MobileModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}


public void GetMobile()
    {
        List<MobileModel> mList = new List<MobileModel>();
        List<MobileModelInfo> modList = new List<MobileModelInfo>();
        MobileModel mob = new MobileModel();

        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Apple";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 6", Catagory = "Premium Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "IOS";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Samsung";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Android";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "MicroSoft";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "Lumina 9900", Catagory = "Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "Opera X220", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Windows";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Sony Ericssion";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Android";
        mList.Add(mob);

        MobileList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModel>(mList);
    }
```

The ObservableCollection MobileList has three properties Brand, Model and OS. The Model Property is again a ObservableCollection in that MobileModelInfo class has three properties Name, Catagory and Year.

I need the Collection it should contain the Year **2011** in the inner collection MobileModelInfo. Rest of the records should not needed.

In Samsung it should contain only

```
mob.Brand = "Samsung";
modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
mob.OS = "Android";
```

Actual Initial Output Screen Shot is
[image: Original List without Filter]

Output Expected is
[image: After Filter]

Comment: If not linq, you could iterate through the model items and get the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var filtered = MobileList.Select(m => new MobileModel {
                Model = new ObservableCollection(m.Model.Where(model => model.Year == "2011").ToList()),
                Brand = m.Brand,
                OS = m.OS
            })
```

;

Comment: I got an Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataGridInWPF.MobileModelInfo>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DataGridInWPF.MobileModelInfo>'

Comment: I improved my answer to use ObservableCollection

Comment: It returns the empty for the Property Brand and OS

Comment: Oh, I see, you just have to copy those, check my updated answer

Answer (score 6):

use `SelectMany()` :

`MobileList.SelectMany(x => x.Model).Where(m=>m.Year==2011)`

Comment: Use the LINQ in the MobileList Property not a mList.

Comment: The Outer Collection Property is Missing. We need to eliminate the Year which is not equal to 2011. But Your LINQ results only MobileModelInfo Collection not a MobileModel.

Comment: I think this may be helpful MobileList.Where(x => x.Model.Any(m=>m.Year==2011))

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use inner where conditions for this.Pls check this:

```
   var result = MobileList.Where(m => m.Model.Where(mdl => mdl.Year =="2011")).ToList();
```

Comment: In the where condition, we should give the bool expression instead of inner where. It will produce an compile time error.

Comment: maybe should use any instead of where like that 'MobileList.Where(m => m.Model.Any(mdl => mdl.Year =="2011")).ToList();'. But sorry i coudnt try this answers.

Comment: i doubt if its even compile